# Can't use exec() function in Python3 to convert a string to an integer

Tags: python

I am converting existing automation code from Python2 to Python3.  There is a call the exec() function in my code as follows:

```
ret = None
exec("ret = %s" % resp)
```

The value of "resp" is '894809'.  In Python2, the value of "ret" would become 894809 as an integer.  In Python3, ret becomes None.  I have to use exec here as other values of ret (objects) are used when calling this code.

Comment: Good, don't use `exec` for that (or for anything else, really). What's wrong with `ret = str(resp)`?

Comment: Actually it's the other way around.  resp comes in as a string, and I want to convert it to an int.  I tried that, but the problem is that other methods call the method where this code is, and pass other types of variables, like objects.  So it has to handle all types of code

Comment: `"resp comes in as a string, and I want to convert it to an int"` well that's the exact opposite of the question's title but this is irrelevant. `exec` is not the correct tool for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: By the way, this worked fine in Python2

Comment: And, to answer the "new" question, use `ret = int(resp)`

Comment: I wish it were that easy... As I said before, other types of data are being passed in to the method where this exec code is, and shouldn't and can't be converted to an int.  In other words, ret and be a string, and object, etc.